# Select option change based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a select.

```
<select>
    <option data-id="0" value="a">a</option>
    <option data-id="1" value="a">a</option>
</select>
```

Dont ask whey they have same values:)

I need to trigger change based on attribute data-id, not on value because values are the same and its going to select first one although maybe I need second one.

This will still select first one:

```
var active_setting = 1;
select.val(select.find("option[data-id='"+active_setting+"']").val());
```

Let say I want to select second one, but of course I dont know nothing about that its second child, I only know data-id.

---

edit:

to answer myself, I solved it like this:

```
select.find("option[data-id='"+active_setting+"']").attr('selected','selected');
select.change();
```

Comment: Are you sure its selecting the first one? Because the values are the same, how can you tell which one it's picking?

Comment: I think your design for your problem is incorrect. Can you explain why exactly you rely on having the same value but different data-id? Thanks.

Comment: I know because I have some values attached to select actions and its picking first one. Also I test like this after change: console.log(select.find(":selected").attr('data-id'))